# Sumar los elementos de dos listas enlazadas en una tercera lista

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

La idea es representar una suma de tres dígitos

```
   6  8  9  <---- valores de lista 1.
   5  7  4   <----- valores lista 2.
 -------------
 1 2  6  3   <------ valores lista 3.
```

Hasta ahora obtengo el resultado de la suma, pero tomando los valores de izquierda a derecha.

```
  6 8 9
  5 7 4
_________
1 4 6 1  ---> regresa el resultado de sumar ( 986 + 474 )
```

Ya intente ingresar los datos en orden contrario en las dos primeras listas y nada.

Les muestro el código:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

struct nodo
{
 int numero;
 struct nodo* sig;
 struct nodo* ant;  
};
typedef struct nodo*Lista;

void insertarValores(Lista &lista,int digito)
{
Lista nuevo;
nuevo = new(struct nodo);
nuevo ->numero=digito;
    if(lista==NULL){
        lista=nuevo;
        lista->sig=NULL;
        lista->ant=NULL;    
    }
    else
    {
        nuevo->sig=lista;
        nuevo->ant=lista->ant;
        lista->ant=nuevo;
        lista=nuevo;
    }   

}
void insertarFinal(Lista & lista,int digito)
{
 Lista nuevo,aux =lista;    
 nuevo = new(struct nodo);
 nuevo->numero=digito;
 nuevo->sig=NULL;
 if(aux==NULL)
 {
    lista=nuevo;
 }
 else
   {
       while(aux->sig!=NULL)
       aux=aux->sig;   
       aux->sig=nuevo;

   }

}

void mostrar(Lista lista)
{

Lista aux =new (struct nodo);

aux=lista;
cout<<"\n";
    while(aux!=NULL){
    cout<<"   "<<aux->numero;
        aux=aux->sig;

    }   
}

void sumar(Lista &lista1,Lista &lista2,Lista &listaResultado)
 {
 Lista l1=lista1, l2=lista2;
  int acarreo=0;
   while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL)
  {
   int suma = l1->numero + l2->numero+acarreo;
   if(suma>=10)
     {
      insertarFinal(listaResultado, suma%10);
      acarreo=1;
     }
    else 
    {
    insertarFinal(listaResultado, suma%10);
    acarreo=0;  
    }
    l1 = l1->sig;
    l2 = l2->sig;
  }
  insertarFinal(listaResultado,acarreo);
}

int main(){
Lista arriba=NULL;
Lista abajo=NULL;
Lista resultado=NULL;
int L1,L2;
cout<<"Ingrese los valores a sumar de la lista 1 (arriba)"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{   cout<<"Lista 1.\n\tValor "<<i+1<<" ";
    cin>>L1;
    //insertarValores(arriba,L1);
    insertarFinal(arriba,L1);
    mostrar(arriba);
        cout<<"\n";
}
system("cls");
cout<<"Ingrese los valores a sumar de la lista 2 (abajo)"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{   cout<<"Lista 2.\n\tValor "<<i+1<<" ";
    cin>>L2;
    //insertarValores(abajo,L2);
insertarFinal(abajo,L2);
mostrar(abajo);
cout<<"\n";
}

system("cls");
mostrar(arriba); 
cout<<"\n+ ";
mostrar(abajo);
cout<<"\n___________________";

sumar(arriba,abajo,resultado);
mostrar(resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que usas una lista doblemente enlazada así que no deberías tener problema alguno en recorrer los números de menos significativo a más significativo.

#### Propuesta

Yo te aconsejaría pasar la lista a número y después dejar que sea el sistema el que se encargue de los acarreos y desbordamientos; la función para pasar tu `Lista` a número sería:

```
int lista_a_numero(const Lista &lista)
{
    int resultado{}, arrastre{1};

    for (const nodo *actual = ultimo(lista); actual; actual = actual->ant)
    {
        resultado += (actual->numero * arrastre);
        arrastre *= 10;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Con esta función podrías transformar la lista en un número. Si te fijas, estoy usando una función para apuntar al último nodo de una lista, la cuál tiene este aspecto:

```
const nodo *ultimo(const nodo *actual)
{
    if (actual->sig)
        return ultimo(actual->sig);

    return actual;
}
```

Ahora sólo necesitas una función que haga la operación inversa para conseguir esto:

```
int valor1 = lista_a_numero(lista1);
int valor2 = lista_a_numero(lista2);
Lista listaSuma = numero_a_lista(valor1 + valor2);
```

La función para trasnformar de número a lista sería algo así:

```
Lista numero_a_lista(int numero)
{
    nodo *resultado = new nodo{numero % 10};
    numero /= 10;

    while (numero)
    {
        resultado = new nodo{numero % 10, resultado};
        resultado->sig->ant = resultado;
        numero /= 10;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Con esta propuesta el código quedaría así:

```
int main()
{
    Lista lista1 = numero_a_lista(689);
    Lista lista2 = numero_a_lista(574);

    int valor1 = lista_a_numero(lista1);
    int valor2 = lista_a_numero(lista2);
    Lista listaSuma = numero_a_lista(valor1 + valor2);

    std::cout << valor1 << " + " << valor2 << " = ";

    for (nodo *actual = listaSuma; actual; actual = actual->sig)
        std::cout << actual->numero;

    return 0;
}
```

[[Cuya salida es]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pE6fT0ZF3s1nZpYM):

> ```
> 689 + 574 = 1263
> ```

#### Consejos

En C++ no es **necesario anteponer `struct` para referirse a una estructura**; así que tu nodo tendría este aspecto:

```
struct nodo
{
 int numero;
 nodo* sig;
 nodo* ant;
};
```

A partir de C++11 puedes usar la [inicialización uniforme](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/inicializadores-de-miembros-en-agregados) para **dar valor a los miembros de tu estructura en el mismo sitio que se declaran**, así te ahorras crear un constructor y te aseguras que obtienen valores controlados:

```
struct nodo
{
 int numero = 0;
 nodo* sig = nullptr;
 nodo* ant = nullptr;
};
```

Para crear alias de tipos, el `typedef` tiene una sintaxis confusa, a partir de C++11 puedes **simplificar el alias con la instrucción `using`**:

```
using Lista = nodo *;
```

Date cuenta que tampoco requiere el `struct` antes de `nodo`.

En cuanto a **este alias, es una idea terrible**, nefasta, horrible, inadecuada, impropia, ilógica y muchos otros calificativos negativos. Un `nodo` no es una `Lista`, conceptualmente son cosas distintas... es como si dijeras que una bujía es un coche; crea un objeto `Lista` no digas que un `nodo` es una `Lista`.

**Usa `const` siempre no modifiques objetos**, eso puede ayudar al compilador a realizar optimizaciones y hace que otros que lean el código conozcan tu intencionalidad:

```
// mostrar una lista no requiere modificarla
void mostrar(const Lista lista);
// no se requiere modificar lista1 ni lista2 para sumar
void sumar(const Lista &lista1, const Lista &lista2, Lista &listaResultado);
```

Comment: Gracias en verdad me ha sido muy útil y sobre todo muy claro donde estaba fallando. También muchas gracias por los consejos tienes toda la razón y que bueno que te tomes la el tiempo de orientarme en ese sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que te has liado un poco en la función suma() ya deberia ser mas simple, así que me di la tarea de alterar un poco tu codigo

```
void sumar(Lista &lista1, Lista &lista2, Lista &listaResultado){    
Lista l1=lista1, l2=lista2;

while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL) {

    int suma = l1->numero + l2->numero;
    insertarFinal(listaResultado, suma);
    l1 = l1->sig;
    l2 = l2->sig;
  }
}
```

Main

```
int main() {

    Lista lista1 = NULL, lista2 = NULL,listaSuma=NULL;
    int n;

   //Llenamos primer lista
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       cout << "Ingrese el valor lista 1 " << endl;
       cin >> n;
       insertarFinal(lista1, n);
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Llenamos segunda lista
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       cout << "Ingrese el valor lista 2" << endl;
       cin >> n;
       insertarFinal(lista2, n);
    }
    cout << endl;

    sumar(lista1, lista2, listaSuma);
    mostrar(listaSuma);

   cin.get();
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

PD: No olvides liberar la memoria.

Comment: Gracias por darte el tiempo de responder. Tienes razón la función suma estaba demasiado enredada. La manera en que lo simplificas esta muy bien, pero sólo he agregado la parte que faltó, el acarreo en las unidades.    Pero el problema sigue :(  ...el acarreo lo hace de izquierda a derecha.

Answer (score 0):

basicamente creas una lista 3 e insertas los nodos de ambas listas con las primitivas de insertar lista en la tercera lista

Comment: Creo que esa lógica estaba clara en la pregunta. ¿Podrías ampliar tu respuesta para explicar cómo sería? Un fragmento de código ayudaría a entender lo que estás respondiendo