# Asignación de punteros en listas enlazadas

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda 'conceptual' y no encuentro recursos o ejercicios para terminar de entenderlo. Es sobre la asignación de un puntero a una lista dinámica para luego seguir insertando (o quitando elementos).

Por ejemplo, no termino de entender por qué no es lo mismo este código (Que funciona e inserta elementos):

```
void insertarPrimero(Nodo*& lista, int v)
{
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo -> info = v;
    nuevo -> sig = lista;
    lista = nuevo;
}
```

Que esté (Que no inserta elementos)

```
void insertarPrimero(Nodo*& lista, int v)
{
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo -> info = v;
    nuevo -> sig = nuevo;
}
```

Mi problema, en todos los ejercicios de este tipo se basa en las sentencias al estilo:

```
lista = nuevo;
```

Lo mismo me pasa con la sentencia que aparece en [este video](https://youtu.be/BGMG3P1cc84?t=13m12s) :

```
pila = nuevo_nodo;
```

Y en la última sentencia del mismo vídeo (el resumen) pero [un poco más adelante](https://youtu.be/BGMG3P1cc84?t=13m26s):

```
Nodo * nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
nuevo_nodo -> info = 15;
nuevo_nodo -> sig = pila;
pila = nuevo_nodo;
```

Les dejo el struct del nodo:

```
struct Nodo
{
    int info;
    Nodo *sig;
};
```

Veo que el problema principal está en que no termino de entender completamente el asunto de los punteros.

Si tienen alguna página con material de lectura adicional y/o ejercicios mejor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Los nodos no son listas. Los nodos no son pilas.

He visto en StackOverflow en Español varias veces esta confusión, y me resulta muy curioso que tantos usuarios cometan ese error, te agradezco que nos hayas facilitado la fuente de ese terrible y confuso error.

En el código que has facilitado se usan variables de nombre `lista` o `pila` cuyo tipo subyacente es un `Nodo`. Y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

#### ¿Qué hace tu código?.

Vamos a ver qué hace cada una de las versiones de `insertarPrimero` que has presentado, asumiendo que `lista` apunta a un nodo aislado (un nodo que no está conectado con otros nodos):

```
void insertarPrimero(Nodo*& lista, int v)
{
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo -> info = v;
    nuevo -> sig = lista;
    lista = nuevo;
}
```

Esta versión de `insertarPrimero`:

1. Crea un nuevo nodo.
2. Añade el dato `v` al nuevo nodo.
3. Enlaza el nuevo nodo con el nodo `lista`.
4. Hace que el nodo `lista` apunte al nuevo nodo.

Visualmente sucede esto:

[image]

Sucesivas llamadas a `insertarPrimero` estarían alargando la lista en base a añadir nodos que siempre se enlazarían manteniendo el más nuevo como primero y el más viejo como último, es decir, funciona como una [pila lifo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_in,_first_out#Inform.C3.A1tica), tras tres inserciones tendría este aspecto:

[image]

Las segunda versión de `insertarPrimero` que has presentado, asumiendo que `lista` apunta a un nodo aislado (un nodo que no está conectado con otros nodos):

```
void insertarPrimero(Nodo*& lista, int v)
{
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo -> info = v;
    nuevo -> sig = nuevo;
}
```

1. Crea un nuevo nodo.
2. Añade el dato `v` al nuevo nodo.
3. Enlaza el nuevo nodo consigo mismo.

Visualmente sucede esto:

[image]

Es a todas luces incorrecto pues se pierde el control de la nueva memoria generada, ya que nadie la está apuntando a ella, tras tres inserciones tendría este aspecto:

[image]

#### Sugerencia.

Para entender este tipo de problemas es muy útil dibujar lo que sucede en memoria. Para desarrollar tu propia lista (por motivos autodidactas, ya que es mejor usar [los contenedores stl](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) y entender estos conceptos, te aconsejo leer las preguntas de otros usuarios de este sitio que se han enfrentado al mismo problema:

- [No se imprimen bien las listas doblemente enlazadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111434/no-se-imprimen-bien-las-listas-doblemente-enlazadas/111517) .
- [Algoritmo de intercambio de nodos de una lista enlazada a través de su índice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91745/algoritmo-de-intercambio-de-nodos-de-una-lista-enlazada-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-su-%C3%ADndice) .
- [Problema al compilar Invertir contenido de una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90959/problema-al-compilar-invertir-contenido-de-una-lista) .
- [duda procedimiento salida por pantalla datos de una lista c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90177/duda-procedimiento-salida-por-pantalla-datos-de-una-lista-c) .
- [Sumar los elementos de dos listas enlazadas en una tercera lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39239/sumar-los-elementos-de-dos-listas-enlazadas-en-una-tercera-lista) .
- [Ayuda para agregar una opcion a un menu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110921/ayuda-para-agregar-una-opcion-a-un-menu) .

Comment: Me encantan tus dibujos... ya estaba yo impacientándome porque no aparecías por esta pregunta

Answer (score 4):

> Por ejemplo, no termino de entender por qué no es lo mismo este código ...

Me da la impresión de que el ejemplo que querías poner de caso que no funcionaba es este:

```
void insertarPrimero(Nodo*& lista, int v)
{
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo -> info = v;
    nuevo -> sig = lista;
    //             ^^^^^ Modificado!!!
}
```

Y la razón por la que no funciona es que estás trabajando con una lista simplemente enlazada, es decir, cada nodo solo tiene un puntero y dirige al siguiente elemento de la lista.

Me explico. Imagina que la lista tiene un elemento con valor `1`:

```
 lista (0x045800)
+---------------+
| info: 1       |
| sig: 0        |
+---------------+
```

Después de llamar a la función que sí funciona el resultado es este:

```
 lista (0x045700)     0x045800
+---------------+    +---------------+
| info: 2       |    | info: 1       |
| sig: 0x045800 | -> | sig: 0        |
+---------------+    +---------------+
```

Sin embargo, la función que no funciona genera el siguiente resultado:

```
 0x045700             lista (0x045800)
+---------------+    +---------------+
| info: 2       |    | info: 1       |
| sig: 0x045800 | -> | sig: 0        |
+---------------+    +---------------+
```

Fíjate que, aunque se ha añadido un nodo por delante, el puntero `lista` no se ha modificado, por lo que ahora apunta al segundo elemento de la lista... como la lista es simple no tienes ningún puntero que te permita acceder al primer nodo... has perdido memoria!!!