# Concatenar dos listas simplemente enlazadas

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de realizar un procedimiento que al recibir dos listas la cargue en un tercera.

Mi estrategia es simple:

- Mientras exista elemento en la lista1 --> Agregar elemento en listaConcatenada.
- Mientras exista elemento en la lista2 --> Agregar elemento en listaConcatenada.

Si embargo a la hora de enlazar las lista1, con la lista concatenada no estoy logrando hacerlo de manera correcta.

El tipo nodo subyacente es el siguiente:

```
struct NodoListaSE
{
    int info;
    NodoListaSE* sig;
};
```

Y mi procedimiento (Pongo el ejemplo para una sola lista):

```
void concatenarLista(NodoListaSE* lista1, NodoListaSE* lista2, NodoListaSE *& listaConcatenada)
{
    NodoListaSE* nuevo = new NodoListaSE();
    while(lista1 != NULL)
    {
        //Asigno el valor de la lista 1 al nuevo nodo.
        nuevo -> info = lista1 -> info;

        nuevo -> sig = listaConcatenada; // <-- Termino agregando elemento de manera infinita.

        listaConcatenada = nuevo;

        lista1 = lista1 -> sig;

        //Contador rudimentario.
        cout << "Valor " <<endl;
    }
}
```

Creo que mi confusión duda está en que no puedo, de manera clara, contestar esta pregunta:

1. ¿Cómo enlazo el nuevo nodo con la lista que paso por parámetro?
2. ¿Cómo 'avanzo' de un elemento a otro?

He estado usando [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115391/asignaci%C3%B3n-de-punteros-en-listas-enlazadas/115649#115649) como guía. Y me sirvió mucho para poder insertar al último lugar, imprimir, calcular promedios y el mayor. Pero no estoy pudiendo concatenar dos listas en una tercera.

Answer (score 2):

#### Los nodos no son listas.

He visto en StackOverflow en Español varias veces esta confusión, y me resulta muy curioso que tantos usuarios cometan ese error.

En el código que has facilitado se usan variables de nombre `lista` cuyo tipo subyacente es un `NodoListaSE`. Y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

#### C++ y C son lenguajes distintos.

Inicialmente habías etiquetado la pregunta con ambos lenguajes; si bien es cierto que muchas soluciones son indistintas del lenguaje, ambos lenguajes tienen una idiosincrasia y estilo muy diferenciados; en concreto C++ suele ser usado más como lenguaje orientado a objetos así que esa función suelta de `concatenarLista`, en estilo C++ formaría parte de un objeto llamado `ListaSE` o sería un operador de suma binario (`+`) pero raramente una función suelta.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta los dos puntos anteriores, yo propondría crear un objeto lista:

```
struct ListaSE
{
    ListaSE() = default;
    ListaSE(ListaSE &&lista);
    ListaSE(const ListaSE &lista);
    ~ListaSE();

    void agrega_dato(int dato);

    ListaSE operator +(const ListaSE &lista) const;
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Concatenador
private:
    struct Nodo
    {
        int info = 0;
        Nodo* sig = nullptr;
    };

    Nodo *raiz = nullptr;
};
```

La manera de concatenar dos listas sería **copiando** todos los nodos, remarco la copia porque queremos una lista nueva resultado de concatenar las dos anteriores no una lista nueva con los nodos de las originales. Una manera de hacerlo sería copiando la `lista1` en una nueva lista y después insertando los datos de la `lista2`:

```
ListaSE operator +(const ListaSE &lista) const
{
    ListaSE resultado(*this); // Copia de la lista actual.

    for (Nodo *nodo = lista.raiz; nodo; nodo = nodo->sig)
        resultado.agrega_dato(nodo->info);

    return resultado;
}
```

Para que mi propuesta funcione tienes que implementar el constructor de copia (`ListaSE(const ListaSE &lista);`) y el constructor de movimiento (`ListaSE(ListaSE &&lista);`):

```
ListaSE::ListaSE(const ListaSE &lista)
{
    for (Nodo *nodo = lista.raiz; nodo; nodo = nodo->sig)
        agrega_dato(nodo->info);
}

ListaSE::ListaSE(ListaSE &&lista)
{
    raiz = lista.raiz;
    lista.raiz = nullptr;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BB03AxvH1RnGuZg9)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Si después de concatenar las listas A y B, no necesitas seguir usando las listas originales; sólo se requiere cambiar un puntero:

El del último nodo de la lista A para que apunte al primer nodo de la lista B.

Piensalo gráficamente:

A: N1 -> N2 -> N3 -> NULL

B: Na -> Nb -> Nc -> NULL

Entonces la concatenación:

C(A,B): N1 -> N2 -> N3 -> (Aquí se cambia NULL por la dirección de Na) Na -> Nb -> Nc -> NULL

Programáticamente sería:

```
    NodoListaSE* concatenarLista(NodoListaSE* lista1, NodoListaSE* lista2)
    {
      NodoListaSE* aux = lista1;
      while (aux->sig != NULL){ // navegar por lista1 hasta el ultimo nodo
        aux = aux->sig;
      }
      /** aqui se que aux apunta al último nodo de lista1,
      solo basta hacer que ultimo_nodo->sig apunte al comienzo de la lista2. Como 
      se pasa argumento (lista1 y lista2) por referencia, la acción se evidencia en todo el 
      programa.
    */
      aux->sig = lista2; // lista2 apunta al primer nodo de la lista2
      return lista1; // lista concatenada queda en lista1 original
    }
```

Si tienes alguna otra duda, comenta esta.
Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

La repuesta depende del tipo de lista que utilices y de la semántica de la operación que quieres implementar.

Como ha dicho Vicente Oyanedel, puede tratarse de un cambio en el último nodo de la primera lista, para que apunte al primer nodo de la segunda lista.

```
Lista1 -> n1 -> n2 -> NULL
Lista2 -> na -> nb -> NULL
Litsa1 (concatenada) -> n1 -> n2 -> na -> nb -> NULL
```

Según esto, la semántica es añadir los elementos de la segunda lista a la primera. El problema es que tienes varias listas apuntando a los mismos nodos, lo que se conoce como `aliasing`. Debes pensar si te conviene permitir el `aliasing` o en tu aplicación esto sería erróneo, y programar en consecuencia.

Por ejemplo, un manejo erróneo del `aliasing` ocurriría si creas un destructor que elimine la lista completa, liberando la memoria de sus nodos, tras haberla concatenado a otra lista.

```
// Se crea una lista con los nodos 1, 2, 3
Nodo * lista1 = new Lista();
lista1->add(1, 2, 3);

// Se crea una lista con los nodos 4 y 5
Nodo * lista2 = new Lista();
lista2->add(4, 5);

// Se concatena: ahora las dos listas apuntan a 4 y 5
lista1->concatenar(lista2);

// Imprimimos las listas
lista1->print();        // lista1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
lista2->print();        // lista2: 4, 5

// Liberamos memoria de los nodos de lista2 (4 y 5)
delete lista2;

// Imprimimos la primera lista
lista1->print();        // error en tiempo de ejecución
```

Al intentar acceder a zonas de memoria ya liberadas, se produciría un error en tiempo de ejecución.

Otra opción, que yo prefiero, es crear una función que dadas dos listas, cree una nueva y vaya insertando copias de los nodos de las dos. Así no se permite el `aliasing`. Esto se acompañaría de una función `addNodo`, que añada un nodo a la lista deseada, previa copia del nodo.

En cualquier caso, la opción a usar es decisión tuya, pero tienes que ser consecuente a la hora de programar para que no se genere problemas con punteros nulos o zonas liberadas pero todavía accesibles erróneamente.

También creo que es mejor definir `Nodo` como `class`, y no como `struct`, ya que, al fin y al cabo, es una clase con los miembros públicos por defecto, encapsulando el comportamiento de un nodo y una lista por separado.

Bueno, yo tengo mi nodo así:

```
class Nodo {
    friend class Lista;
    private:
        int valor;
        Nodo * sig;
    public:
        Nodo(int v);
        ~Nodo();
};
```

Y mi lista así:

```
class Lista {
    private:
        Nodo * primero;
        Nodo * ultimo;
        int elementos;
    public:
        Lista();
        ~Lista();
        void addNodo(Nodo * nodo);
        Lista * concatenar(Lista * l);
};
```

Como he comentado, la función `addNodo` copia el nodo y lo inserta en la lista, de tal manera que se impide el `aliasing`.

La función `concatenarListas` la he hecho estática, recibe dos listas y devuelve un nueva lista que contiene copias de los nodos de ambas.

El código de la concatenación con copia es:

```
Lista * Lista::concatenar(Lista * l) {
    if (l == NULL) throw "Error: lista nula";

    Lista * lista = new Lista();

    Nodo * nodo = this->primero;
    while (nodo != NULL) {
        lista->add(nodo);
        nodo = nodo->sig;
    }

    nodo = l->primero;
    while (nodo != NULL) {
        lista->add(nodo);
        nodo = nodo->sig;
    }

    return lista;
}
```

esta función se basa en la función `addNodo`, que no permite el `aliasing`, y que es así:

```
void Lista::add(Nodo * n) {
    if (n == NULL) throw "Error: nodo nulo";

    Nodo * copia = new Nodo(n->valor);

    if (elementos == 0) {
        primero = copia;
        ultimo = copia;
    }
    else {
        ultimo->sig = copia;
        ultimo = copia;
    }

    elementos++;
}
```