# Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION durante ejecución de programa

Tags: c++

Tengo siguiente error cuando intento ejecutar el siguiente codigo. Estoy trabajando con Eclipse C++ y Cywing.

```
Error:
**      3 [main] ArbolABB 4024 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to ArbolABB.exe.stackdump
**

**Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=004012CF
eax=5C726F74 ebx=0064CC4C ecx=0064CA08 edx=00000000 esi=2007172D edi=20071721
ebp=0064CBB8 esp=0064CBA0 program=C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\Proyecto\ArbolABB\Debug\ArbolABB.exe, pid 4024, thread main
cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0064CBB8  004012CF (5C726F74, 611C5D40, 00403073, 0064CBE8)
0064CBD8  004012DA (0064CC68, 200716E8, 004030A9, 0064CC04)
0064CBF8  004012FD (0064CC4C, 00000000, 00000000, 6107CA33)
0064CC28  0040153D (00000001, 0064CC4C, 200280F0, 610079C2)
0064CD18  61007A27 (00000000, 0064CD74, 61006A20, 00000000)
End of stack trace
**
```

Este es el código que estoy ejecutando.

**ArbolABB.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
 using namespace std;

 typedef struct nodo{
 int numero;
 struct nodo *nodoIzquierdo;
 struct nodo *nodoDerecho;
 }*ABB;

 int numeroDeNodos = 0;


 ABB crearNodo(int valor)
 {
 ABB nuevoNodo = new(struct nodo);
 nuevoNodo-> numero = valor;
 nuevoNodo-> nodoIzquierdo = NULL;
 nuevoNodo-> nodoDerecho = NULL;

 return nuevoNodo;
 }
 void insertar(ABB &arbol, int valor)
 {
 if(arbol == NULL)
 {
       arbol = crearNodo(valor);
       printf("\n\t Nodo Insertado");
 }
 else if(valor < arbol -> numero)
      insertar(arbol-> nodoIzquierdo, valor);
 else if(valor > arbol-> numero)
      insertar(arbol-> nodoDerecho, valor);
 }

  void preOrden(ABB arbol)
 {
 if(arbol != NULL)
 {
     printf("%d ", arbol -> numero);
     preOrden(arbol -> nodoIzquierdo);
     preOrden(arbol -> nodoDerecho);
 }
 }

 void enOrden(ABB arbol)
 {
 if(arbol != NULL)
 {
      enOrden(arbol -> nodoIzquierdo);
      printf("%d ", arbol -> numero);
      enOrden(arbol -> nodoDerecho);
 }
 }

 void postOrden(ABB arbol)
 {
 if(arbol != NULL)
 {
      enOrden(arbol -> nodoIzquierdo);
      enOrden(arbol -> nodoDerecho);
      printf("%d ", arbol -> numero);
 }
 }

 bool busqueda(ABB arbol, int valorABuscar)
 {
 int aux= 0;

 if(arbol == NULL)
    return aux;

 if(valorABuscar < arbol -> numero)
     aux = busqueda(arbol -> nodoIzquierdo, valorABuscar);

 else if(valorABuscar > arbol -> numero)
     aux = busqueda(arbol-> nodoDerecho, valorABuscar);

 else
    aux = 1;

 return aux;
 }

 ABB unir(ABB nIzquierda, ABB nDerecha)
{
if(nIzquierda == NULL)
    return nDerecha;
if(nDerecha == NULL)
    return nIzquierda;

ABB centro = unir(nIzquierda -> nodoDerecho, nDerecha -> nodoIzquierdo);
nIzquierda -> nodoDerecho = centro;
nDerecha -> nodoIzquierdo = nIzquierda;
return nDerecha;
}

void elimina(ABB &arbol, int valor)
{
 if(arbol == NULL) return;

 if(valor < arbol -> numero)
     elimina(arbol -> nodoIzquierdo, valor);
 else if(valor > arbol -> numero)
     elimina(arbol -> nodoDerecho, valor);
 else
 {
     ABB aux = arbol;
     arbol = unir(arbol -> nodoIzquierdo, arbol -> nodoDerecho);
     delete aux;
 }
 }

 int main() {
ABB arbol;
insertar(arbol, 15);
insertar(arbol, 9);
insertar(arbol, 6);
insertar(arbol, 14);
insertar(arbol, 13);
insertar(arbol, 20);
insertar(arbol, 17);
insertar(arbol, 64);
insertar(arbol, 26);
insertar(arbol, 72);
elimina(arbol, 15);
printf("\n");
printf("Busqueda (0 = no encontrado, 1 = encontrado): %d",busqueda(arbol, 13));
printf("\nEnOrden: ");
enOrden(arbol);
printf("\nPostOrden: ");
postOrden(arbol);
printf("\nPreOrden: ");
preOrden(arbol);

}
```

Cuanto ejecuto este código en mi computador personal lo ejecuta perfectamente pero cuando lo exporto y lo intento usar en una laptop que tengo no me lo ejecuta y sale el error antes mencionado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Un nodo no es un árbol

Al igual que una pera no es una manzada, un nodo no representa a un árbol.

Como repetir no es bueno, hay algunas respuestas en StackOverflow que ya tratan este tema, como por ejemplo [ésta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115649/463)

### Inicializa las variables

Otro problema de tu código es que no inicializas las variables, luego al programa le es imposible saber si un puntero es válido o no... hasta que el sistema operativo le da con el palo en la cabeza.

```
ABB arbol;
insertar(arbol, 15);
```

En principio el código anterior no parece demasiado peligroso... al fin y al cabo, si miramos la función `insertar`:

```
void insertar(ABB &arbol, int valor)
{
  if(arbol == NULL)
```

Vemos que lo primero que hace es comprobar si el puntero es nulo... pero la guarda se viene abajo cuando el puntero no está inicializado. C++ se ha diseñado con la idea de que sea lo más rápido posible (otra cosa es que siempre se consiga) y ello tiene consecuencias... la más evidente en este caso es que cuando se declara una variable, la misma no se va inicializar por defecto y su valor inicial dependerá de lo que hubiese almacenado en la memoria en la que se ubica... Las probabilidades de que `arbol` empiece apuntando a 0 son de 1/2^32 (e incluso puede que más bajas) así que si te sale más te vale que te vayas a una casa de apuestas antes de que se te acabe la suerte.

La solución a este problema es trivial:

```
AAB arbol = nullptr; /* o 0 o NULL si no compilas con C++11 */
```

Corrigiendo esto tu programa ya funcionará, pero te aconsejo seguir leyendo.

### C++ no es C

Y el operador `new` no es `malloc`. Esto:

```
ABB nuevoNodo = new(struct nodo);
```

Queda más legible así:

```
ABB nuevoNodo = new nodo;
```

### Usa los constructores

Por otro lado, en C++ existe el concepto de constructor, que permite inicializar los miembros de un objeto sin tener que hacer llamadas explícitas:

```
struct nodo{
 int numero;
 struct nodo *nodoIzquierdo;
 struct nodo *nodoDerecho;

 nodo()
   : numero(0), 
     nodoIzquierdo(nullptr),
     nodoDerecho(nullptr)
 { }
};
```

Usando constructores tu código quedará más limpio:

- Sin constructor:

  ```
  ABB crearNodo(int valor)
  {
    ABB nuevoNodo = new(struct nodo);
    nuevoNodo-> numero = valor;
    nuevoNodo-> nodoIzquierdo = NULL;
    nuevoNodo-> nodoDerecho = NULL;

    return nuevoNodo;
  }
  ```
- Con constructor:

  ```
  ABB crearNodo(int valor)
  {
    return new nodo;
  }
  ```

Y poco más que añadir, cuando pruebes tu código verás que la ordenación falla ligeramente... pero pegarte con eso es parte de tu ejercicio, así que ahí no me meto.