# Suma de matrices a partir de un archivo de texto

Tags: c, matrices

¡Buen día!.Tengo que realizar un programa donde se sumen 2 matrices a partir de un archivo, pero no tengo idea de como juntar los códigos. En la imagen se muestra lo que se me pide y en el segundo programa a la hora de ejecutar, no importa que números se encuentren en el archivo de texto, siempre pone cero. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?. El programa que estoy ocupando es lcc-win

El enunciado es el siguiente:

> El programa realiza lo siguiente:
>
> 1. pide al usuario el nombre del archivo de entrada de datos(archivo de datos numéricos: los dos primeros datos enteros indicando el numero de filas y columnas de las matrices; luego los datos numéricos de punto flotante de las dos matrices, uno por renglón).
> 2. realiza la suma de las matrices mostrando los resultados en pantalla.
> 3. pregunta al usuario el nombre de un archivo de salida.
> 4. guarda las tres matrices en el archivo de salida con estructura de matrices por filas y columnas.
> 5. cierra el archivo y termina.

Y los programas que tengo ahora mismo son los siguientes:

```
/* Suma de matrices */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, m, n; /* variables para matrices */
    printf("Suma de matrices.\n");
    printf("Introduce numero de filas:  ");
    scanf("%2d", &m);
    printf("Introduce numero de columnas: ");
    scanf("%2d", &n);
    float a[m][n];
    float b[m][n];
    float c[m][n];
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            printf("Introduce elemento A[%2d,%2d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%f", &a[i - 1][j - 1]);
        }
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            printf("Introduce elemento B[%2d,%2d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%f", &b[i - 1][j - 1]);
        }
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            c[i - 1][j - 1] = a[i - 1][j - 1] + b[i - 1][j - 1];
    printf("'nMatriz A.\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            printf(" %6.2f ", a[i - 1][j - 1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nMatriz B.\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            printf(" %6.2f ", b[i - 1][j - 1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nMatriz C.\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            printf(" %6.2f ", c[i - 1][j - 1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* Este programa lee dos matrices */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

    int main(void)
{
    int m, n, i, j, k = 0;
    char s_entrada[60];
    clrscr();
    printf("Lee dos matrices de punto flotante\n");
    printf("a partir de un archivo.\n");
    printf("Los dos primeros numeros son los que indican el numero de filas y columnas.\n");
    printf("Se leen los datos a los arreglos a[m][n] y b[m][n]\n\n");
    printf("Archivo de entrada");
    while ((s_entrada[k] = getchar()) != '\n')
        k++;
    s_entrada[k] = '\0';
    k = 0;
    FILE* entrada;
    entrada = fopen(s_entrada, "r");
    if (entrada == NULL)
        printf("Error al abrir archivo de entrada.\n");
    else {
        printf("Exito al abrir: %s \n", s_entrada);
        fscanf(entrada, "%d", &m);
        fscanf(entrada, "%d", &n);
        double a[m][n];
        double b[m][n];
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                fscanf(entrada, "%1f", &a[i][j]);
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                fscanf(entrada, "%1f", &b[i][j]);
        fclose(entrada);
        printf("\n\nArreglo a[%2d][%2d].\n", m, n);
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                printf("%10.21f ", a[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\nArreglo b[%2d][%2d].\n", m, n);
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                printf("%10.21f ", b[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creo que puedes introducir el código de forma normal. Este sitio solo ejecuta JavaScript, CSS, HTML

Comment: La imagen no se ve bien ¿podrías, en lugar de pegar la imagen, copiar el texto?

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Como te comenta @Paula_plus_plus, esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Usa [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de formato establecidas: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: ¿Seguro que el programa es [tag:c++]? El código es completamente [tag:c] (tanto en cabeceras y formato como en funciones).

Comment: el programa es lcc-win32, pero no encuentro ningún sitio web que pueda ayudarme, y lo que mejor vi fue que c++ se le asemeja

Comment: ¿Pero con qué lenguaje estás trabajando? Si el lenguaje es C y te damos una respusta en C++ es bastante probable que no te sirva

Comment: Es lenguaje en C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lectura de cadenas de caracteres

Para leer el nombre del fichero no hace falta complicarse la vida de esta manera:

```
while ((s_entrada[k] = getchar()) != '\n')
        k++;
    s_entrada[k] = '\0';
```

Basta con usar `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s",s_entrada);
```

El resultado será prácticamente el mismo. La desventaja más acusada es que en este caso el fichero no puede tener espacios... aunque hay alternativas más bonitas a la que has propuesto para ello. Las ventajas:

- Menos código => menos puntos de error
- Más legible => más dificil meter la pata

### No uses VLA

Es algo recurrente así que, por no repetirme, me remito a, por ejemplo, esta otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115649/463) donde explico el tema.

El caso es que la memoria de las matrices tendrías que reservarla así:

```
double **a = (double**)malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
  a[i] = (double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
```

Y al usar memoria dinámica no hay que olvidarse de liberarla:

```
for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
  free(a[i]);
free(a);
```

Si te parece un código engorroso (que lo es), basta con aislarlo en una función para hacerlo más reutilizable:

```
double** NuevaMatriz(int filas, int columnas)
{
  double **a = (double**)malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
  for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
    a[i] = (double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
}

void LiberaMatriz(double **matriz)
{
  for( int i=0; i<m; i++ )
    free(a[i]);
  free(a);      
}
```

### Al usar decimales, no es lo mismo leer que escribir

Cuando quieres imprimir un número decimal sueles utilizar `%f`, que funciona muy bien tanto para `float` como para `double`:

```
float  num1 = 1.5;
double num2 = 1.5;
printf("%f %f",num1,num2);
```

Y esto funcionará bien ya que `printf` convertirá `num2` a `float` para imprimirlo.

Peeero la lectura no funciona igual:

```
float  num1;
double num2;
scanf("%f %f",&num1,&num2); // <<--- OJO!!!
```

Y el motivo es que ahora estás pasando punteros y mientras las variables por valor pueden ser promocionadas, los punteros no poseen esta característica.

`float` ocupa 4 bytes, mientras que `double`, 8. Y no solo eso sino que además el tamaño de la mantisa y el exponente también cambia. `scanf` no sabe si el puntero pertenece a un tipo `float` o a un tipo `double`... como tu le dices que lea un `float` (que es lo que representa el `%f`, `scanf` se limita a almacenar el dato leído en formato `float`, lo cual resulta en un número extraño para el tipo `double`:

```
       | 0x00 | 0x01 | ... | 0x08 | 0x09 | 0x0A | 0x0B | ... | 0x1F | 0x20 | ... | 0x3F | 0x40 |
float  | SIGN | EXPONENTE  | MANTISA                                       | SIN USO ...       |
double | SIGN | EXPONENTE                              | MANTISA                               |
```

Para leer `double` hay que utilizar `%lf`:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    fscanf(entrada, "%lf", &a[i][j]);
```

La diferencia con tu código es que tu estás usando `%1f`, es decir, un *uno* en vez de la letra *ele*.

### Suma de matrices

Una vez tienes las matrices leidas, sumarlas es trivial basta con que copies lo que has hecho (si realmente ese código es tuyo) en el primer programa el bucle que realiza dicha suma.

Esta parte no te la hago porque si no no vas a aprender.

### Guardar los datos en el fichero

Esta parte no la has ni empezado, así que por el momento no tiene errores y, por tanto, no hay nada que comentar al respecto.