# Invertir una serie numérica utilizando función getchar()

Tags: c, array, caracteres

**Objetivo del programa :**

- Lo que intenta este programa simple a modo de auto estudio es usar las función *getchar()* y dos simples arreglos para invertir una serie numérica.

Mi forma de ver la dinámica a usar(Ayúdame a entender el caos :S)

- Para eso declaro dos arreglos con sus respectivas variables de tamaño los cuales son `run[a]` y `run_inv[b]`.
- En *run[a]* almacenare una serie por ejemplo "12345678" usando la función ya mencionada `getchar()`, que para quienes no la conozcan es como un `scanf`, con la diferencia que no toma todo como un `string`, sino que toma carácter a carácter. Por ende si se quiere guardar una serie,se debe usar un bucle, de lo contrario se guardara solo el primer carácter.
- Luego se procede a invertir el arreglo con otro bucle y otro arreglo respectivamente.
- Desde ahí parte el menjunje. según el ejemplo si ingreso 12345678, entonces '`a=8`' por lo que decidí crear una variable llamada `cont` la cual usare como indicador contador *'a'* con la intención de no modificar el valor de '`a`' quedando con valor '`cont=a-1`',¿Porqué? he aquí una ilustración del porque:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve no existe un `run[8]`, por ende `cont=a-1` o mas bien `cont=7` me sirve para indicar cual es el último termino de mi arreglo `run[a]`

Entonces procederé a explicar que es lo que pasa, para ver si me dan una ayudita:

- Primero en un bucle tipo `for` la sentencia dice que el contador `b` partirá en 0 y aumentara mientras `b<=(a-1)`  a en este caso es 7, ya que en esa posición esta el último valor del arreglo a invertir (`run[7]=8`).
- Lo primero que hice en el bucle fue llenar la primera posición del nuevo arreglo con la ultima del primer arreglo de esta forma `run_inv[b]=run[cont]` (en esta instancia `b=0` y `cont=7`).
- Luego de esto ya se guardo la primera posición de `run_inv[0]` con el valor 8.
- Ahora solo queda ir jugando con el contador `cont` para que vaya disminuyendo mientras `b` avanzara al final de cada ciclo.
- El programa me funciona bien si ingreso hasta una serie de 5 números consecutivos.

**Se invirtio de forma correcta la serie ingresada (12345)**
[image]

**Aqui ya se ve un problema que no puedo entender con el ingreso de un numero mas: Observa lo que pasa en las siguientes capturas con series de mas de 5 numeros**

**(123456)**
[image]

**(123456789)**
[image]

**CODIGO**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,cont,run[a],run_inv[b];

    printf("Por favor ingresar Run sin codigo verificador :     ");
    for(a=0;(c=getchar())!=EOF;a++)
        {
            if(a==0)
            {
                printf("\nARREGLO 'run[a]' CARACTERISTICAS & LLENADO\n\n");
            }
            if(c!=10)                                                                       //si es igual a 10 genera un espacio vacio sin valor de tipo entero.
            {
                if(c!=46)                                                                   //a modo de proactica, el 46 en ANSI me sirve para omicion de los '.' (puntos) en el arreglo.
                {
                    run[a]=c;                                                               //arreglo 'run[a]' sera llenado desde posicion 0 con cada caracter relativo al orden de entrada.
                    printf("Posicion    run[a]: %i \tValor: %c  en ANSI: %i\n",a,run[a],run[a]);
                }
                else continue;
            }
            else break;
        }//hasta aqui el programa me va perfecto!! la serie se guarda de forma perfecta en el orden indicado!!
    cont=a-1;                                                                           //'cont' solo es un indicador de posición que usare de referencia para invertir el arreglo
    printf("\nCantidad de numeros ingresados=   %i\n\n",a);
    printf("\nARREGLO INVERTIDO 'run_inv[b]'\n\n");

    for(b=0;b<=(a-1);b++)                                                               //leera hasta la posicion a-1 para evitar el error del espacio vacio y desencaje
    {
        run_inv[b]=run[cont];
        printf("Posicion run_inv[%i]: %c    Posicion run[%i]:   %c\n",b,run_inv[b],cont,run[cont]);
        cont--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**POR FAVOR**
Yo estudio por mi cuenta y me encanta!. Es por eso que agradecería mucho que me explicasen el origen de este problema, y como solucionarlo de la forma en que lo desarrolle yo y si hay alguna otra forma de llegar al mismo fin también me encantaría saberlo como aprendizaje extra.(*Pero me entusiasma mucho mas saber cual es mi fallo con el procedimiento empleado*)...

Comment: Estas en un sitio de programadores. Personalmente, tanto texto me aburre y me quita las ganas. Con el código mínimo, lo que esperas, lo que obtienes y un mínimo de contexto, es mas que suficiente :-)

Comment: @Trauma tu nick hace honor a la verdad xD, Me parece que la pregunta está bien, da absolutamente todos los datos que hacen falta, y bueno, aunque puede que sobre un poco la parte del final, ya que no influye en la pregunta, tampoco está mal, siempre sienta bien saber que hay personas con afán de aprender por cualquier medio posible :)

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil Fíjate que he dicho `Personalmente ...`. A mi me sobra mas del 50% de lo que ha puesto, incluidas las imágnes (que no son recomendables, y se pueden reemplazar por un par de líneas de texto).

Comment: @Trauma eso es cierto, se podría resumir mucho mas la pregunta sin perder información, si te parece que podría estar mejor formulada, siempre puedes editarla, y así ganar un par de puntillos ;)

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil Hace **mucho** que no puedo ganar *puntillos* editando :-p Y es preferible que edite el OP, para que vaya aprendiendo :-)

Comment: @Trauma otra cosa en la que tienes razón.

Comment: Es mi primer post en la vida, y muchas gracias a ambos por sus sugerencias, de verdad tomare sus sugerencias tanto en como hacer un post y tbn sobre los errores de codificación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nada más iniciar tu programa tienes esto:

```
int a,b,c,cont,run[a],run_inv[b];
```

Esta línea tan tonta tiene varios problemas graves:

- `a` y `b` no están inicializados, luego el tamaño de `run` y `run_inv` es un misterio.
- ¿Qué sucedería si `a` o `b` tuvesen un valor negativo? ¿y si es cero?
- `run` y `run_inv` son VLA, algo que no forma parte del estándar. Para más detalles puedes mirar, por ejemplo, en esta otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115649/463)
- `run` y `run_inv` van a almacenar caracteres.... ¿por qué son arrays de tipo `int`?

Dado que pretendes que el tamaño de `run` y `run_inv` sea variable te toca usar memoria dinámica.

Como a priori no sabes cuántos elementos va a tener la secuencia tendrás que ir redimensionando la reserva sobre la marcha:

```
char *run, *run_inv;
run = 0; /* o NULL, como prefieras */
printf("Por favor ingresar Run sin codigo verificador :     ");
for(a=0;c=getchar(), c!=EOF;a++)
{
  if(a==0)
  {
    printf("\nARREGLO 'run[a]' CARACTERISTICAS & LLENADO\n\n");
  }
  if(c!=10) //si es igual a 10 genera un espacio vacio sin valor de tipo entero.
  {
    if(c!=46) //a modo de proactica, el 46 en ANSI me sirve para omicion de los '.' (puntos) en el arreglo.
    {
      run = (char*)realloc(run,(a+1)*sizeof(char));
      run[a]=c; //arreglo 'run[a]' sera llenado desde posicion 0 con cada caracter relativo al orden de entrada.
      printf("Posicion    run[a]: %i \tValor: %c  en ANSI: %i\n",a,run[a],run[a]);
    }
    else continue;
  }
  else break;
}
```

Con `run_inv` no tenemos ese problema, ya que no necesitamos usarlo hasta que no hayamos leido completamente la secuencia... momento en el que sabemos el tamaño que va a tener:

```
cont=a-1; //'cont' solo es un indicador de posición que usare de referencia para invertir el arreglo
run_inv = (char*)malloc((a+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Y ya solo nos queda liberar la memoria una vez deje de ser necesaria:

```
free(run);
free(run_inv);
return 0;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!
tomare todas tus sugerencias, master solo quiero seguir aprendiendo...
PD: mucho texto muy latero... lo se, solo que quizas tambien sirva a personas que se estan iniciando en este lenguaje