# ¿Cómo poner una cola en una lista doble enlazada en c++?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, punteros, struct

Estoy trabajando en una tarea universitaria sobre **estructuras de datos en c++**.

La idea de lo que estoy tratando de hacer es:

1. Crear una lista doblemente enlazada de nombre Departamento(de trabajo).
2. Insertar una cola de empleados en cada nodo departamento que el usuario cree.

Las implementaciones que ya he realizado es la **lista doblemente enlazada**

```
struct nodo{
    Departamento departamento;
    nodo* siguiente;
    nodo* anterior;
    struct nodoCola* empleados;
}*primero, *ultimo, *dpt=NULL;
```

Y para insertar el departamento tengo. Debo aclarar que tengo la restricción de crear las estructuras con **struct** y **punteros** y no usando clases de C++.

```
void insertarDepartamento(Departamento _departamento){

    nodo* nuevo = new nodo();
    nuevo->departamento = _departamento;

    if(primero == NULL){
        primero = nuevo;
        primero->siguiente = NULL;
        primero->anterior = NULL;
        ultimo = primero;
    }else{
        ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
        nuevo->anterior = ultimo;
        nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }

    cout<< "\nDatos ingresados" <<endl;
}
```

Mi problema es que no he conseguido agregar una lista de empleados. Gráficamente lo que busco es algo como esto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, tengo mis nodos departamento que internamente tienen cada uno una cola de empleados.

La cola del empleado la tengo de esta forma:

```
struct nodoCola{
    Empleado empleado;
    nodoCola* siguiente;
}*primero_, *ultimo_, *empleadoCola;
```

Por el momento lo que he intentado para añadir un empleado al nodo de un departamento es:

```
void insertarEmpleadoADepartamento(Empleado _empleado, int idDepartamento){

            nodo* actual = new nodo(); //El nodo del departamento
            primero = actual;            

              //Búsqueda del identificador en la lista doble enlazada
            while(actual != NULL){  
                if(actual->departamento.GetnumDepartamento() == idDepartamento){
                        //Agregar aquí el empleado a la lista doble enlazada
                      cout<<"EMPLEADO INSERTADO"<<endl;                         

                    break;
                }else{
                    cout<<"DEPARTAMENTO NO ENCONTRADO"<<endl;
                }

                actual = actual->siguiente;
            }
}
```

El `idDepartamento` es un identificador de cada departamento que agrego; pensé que buscando ese identificador encontraría el nodo que necesito para insertar al empleado.

Tengo en el archivo de la cola el método de insertar empleado, aunque no se si me sirva para agregar a la lista de departamento.

```
void insertarEmpleado(Empleado empleado_){

        nodoCola* nuevo = new nodoCola();
        nuevo->empleado = empleado_;

        if(primero_ == NULL){
            primero_ = nuevo;
            primero_->siguiente = NULL;
            ultimo_ = primero_;

            cout<<"Empleado agregado"<<endl;
        }else{
            ultimo_->siguiente = nuevo;
            nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
            ultimo_ = nuevo;
            cout<<"Empleado agregado"<<endl;
        }
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar con esta pregunta lo agradeceré eternamente. Aún me estoy familiarizando con el tema de **struct** y **punteros** en código c++.

Por favor revisen mis struct que he escrito y díganme si le hace falta algo o está mal escrito para lo que intento hacer.

Lo más seguro es que sea algo de punteros que tengo en los `struct`.

Comment: Mola eso de trabajar en C++ y no usar clases... para eso que te pongan a programar en C. Por cierto, has de saber que la única diferencia entre `struct` y `class` es la visibilidad por defecto, en `struct` es `public` mientras que en `class` es `private`. En todo lo demás son **exactamente** iguales. Siento decirlo así pero tu profesor no debería dar clases de programación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es lo primero. Un nodo **no es** una lista. Un nodo es un elemento de una lista... sería como decir que una mano es una persona. Mezclar conceptos y responsabilidades ayuda enormemente a que los programas no funcionen o sean complicados de entender y de mantener. Para más información (es un tema que se ha comentado varias veces), puedes consultar [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115649/463)

Además no deberías usar variables globales tan alegremente. Te quedaría todo más recogido y elegante separando los conceptos de nodo y lista:

```
struct lista_departamentos
{
  nodo* primero;
  nodo* ultimo;
};
```

El implementar este mecanismo es cosa tuya, por mi parte no es más que una sugerencia, el resto de la respuesta no tendrá en cuenta ese apartado para no apartarnos de lo que se pregunta.

El primer error que tienes en la función `insertarEmpleadoADepartamento` es que estás sobreescribiendo la lista de departamentos:

```
void insertarEmpleadoADepartamento(Empleado _empleado, int idDepartamento){

        nodo* actual = new nodo(); //El nodo del departamento
        primero = actual; // <<--- AQUI!!!
```

Se supone que el departamento debe existir, luego no hay ninguna necesidad de crear un nodo de departamento en esta función.

Por otro lado, para insertar un empleado en un departamento tienes, como bien has hecho, localizar el departamento en cuestión, pero te falta el código que inserta al empleado en el departamento:

```
void insertarEmpleadoADepartamento(Empleado _empleado, int idDepartamento)
{
  nodo* actual = primero;

  //Búsqueda del identificador en la lista doble enlazada
  while(actual != NULL)
  {
    if(actual->departamento.GetnumDepartamento() == idDepartamento)
    {

        nodoCola* nuevo = new nodoCola();                        
        nuevo->empleado = _empleado;                            

           nodoCola* _ultimo = NULL;

              if(actual->empleados == NULL){
                  actual->empleados = nuevo;
                  actual->empleados->siguiente = NULL;
                  _ultimo = actual->empleados;
                  actual->empleados->ultimoCola = _ultimo;
                    cout<<"EMPLEADO INSERTADO CABEZA"<<endl;
              }else{

                  actual->empleados->ultimoCola->siguiente = nuevo;
                  nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
                  actual->empleados->ultimoCola = nuevo;
                  cout<<"EMPLEADO INSERTADO COLA"<<endl;                         

              }                
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"DEPARTAMENTO NO ENCONTRADO"<<endl;
    }

    actual = actual->siguiente;
  }
}
```

Fíjate que no estoy usando las variables **globales** que has declarado de tipo `nodoCola`. Si usas esas variables globales entonces únicamente existirá **una** lista de empleados... y tu necesitas que existan varias (más concretamente una por departamento).

Un inciso adicional. Si separas, como te he comentado, los conceptos nodo y lista el código es más expresivo y limpio. Ya no habrá que verificar si la lista de empleados *existe* (algo que no tiene sentido ya que la lista siempre debería existir... otra cosa es que esté vacía o no).

```
void insertarEmpleadoADepartamento(Empleado _empleado, int idDepartamento)
{
  nodo* actual = primero;

  //Búsqueda del identificador en la lista doble enlazada
  while(actual != NULL)
  {
    if(actual->departamento.GetnumDepartamento() == idDepartamento)
    {
      nodoCola* nuevo = new nodoCola;
      nuevo->siguiente = nullptr;

      lista_empleados = actual->empleados;
      if( nullptr == lista_empleados->primero)
        lista_empleados->primero = nuevo;
      else
         lista_empleados->ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;

      lista_empleados->ultimo = nuevo;

      cout<<"EMPLEADO INSERTADO"<<endl;                         
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"DEPARTAMENTO NO ENCONTRADO"<<endl;
    }

    actual = actual->siguiente;
  }
}
```